# How to create a custom nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a default dict which looks like :

```
original=
    {
      'cat': [
        18.919298,
        20.39386,
        20.39386,
        14.010526,
        16.508772,
        16.508772,
        15.34386
      ],
      'dog': [
        24.716667,
        24.716667,
        24.716667,
        21.563121,
        21.563121
      ],
      'wolf': [
        15.761111,
        15.761111,
        15.761111
      ],
      'tiger': [
        7.961111,
        7.055556,
        70.988889,
        35.527778
      ],
      'elephant': [
        37.386364,
        28.289394,
        28.289394,
        35.930303,
        35.930303
      ],
      'pythons': [
        18.399561,
        18.399561,
        28.431798,
        28.431798,
        19.839735,
        22.66557,
        20.986842,
        18.674232,
        18.674232,
        18.248904
      ]
    }
```

Now i want to persome some operation which returns me a list , now i want my final dict to look something like

```
  'cat': { 'original':[
              18.919298,
              20.39386,
              20.39386,
              14.010526,
              16.508772,
              16.508772,
              15.34386
            ],
            'result':[
            1,
            2,
            3,
            ]
  },
 . 
 .
```

I was trying something like this :

```
modified_dict = {}
for key,value in original.items(): 
    result = [1,2,3] # Assume that a function returns me the data here as dict
    modified_dict[rrd]['original']=values
    modified_dict[rrd]['result'] = result
```

I know the last part of code is not correct and hence i need help to get that part working. Can someone please look and help me with what exactly i am missing to get the new modified dict as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

try `dict comprehension` instead.

```
result = [1,2,3]

{k : {"original": v, "result": result} for k, v in original.items()}
```

---

```
{'cat': {'original': [18.919298,
                      20.39386,
                      20.39386,
                      14.010526,
                      16.508772,
                      16.508772,
                      15.34386],
         'result': [1, 2, 3]},
 'dog': {'original': [24.716667, 24.716667, 24.716667, 21.563121, 21.563121],
         'result': [1, 2, 3]},
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your dictionary in-place:

```
for key in original:
    original[key] = {'original': original[key], 'result': ...}
```

Or you can do it by making a new dictionary:

```
modified = {}
for key, value in original.items():
    modified[key] = {'original': value, 'result': ...}
```

In both cases, to need to create a new nested dictionary for each value.

If you have a function of the key and value that returns the result, you can write the latter version as a comprehension:

```
modified = {key: {'original': value, 'result': func(key, value)} for key, value in original.items()}
```